# android - notifications without alerting the user

Tags: android

I currently have an ongoing notification that displays some information about my app. While this information is useful, there's no need for the user to actually see that I've created the notification. Its basically there to tell them that "hey, my app is doing stuff in the background, click here to go back to it".

My notification works correctly, however whenever I call ".notify()" my notification shows the text from my notification in the notification bar at the top of the screen, like a text message does.

I want to to do it silently, so when I call notify it doesn't show my notifications text in the small notification bar before doing the "roll up" animation.

```
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, AudioPlayer.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            title, System.currentTimeMillis());

    RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
            R.layout.note_layout);

    ~~~ remote views stuff ~~~


    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_title, title);
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_text, author);
    notification.contentView = contentView;
    notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT; 
    mNotificationManager.notify(8675309, notification);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that the OS allow that.

What you want to hide is called Ticker.

You can try to set an empty Ticker Text:

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            "", System.currentTimeMillis());
```